# When using Spark Connector with Snowflake, where that query is processed?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

For example if i run a query using Spark Connector from a client (running on EMR - 1) to get data from Snowflake (running on EMR - 2), where that query is actually executed ? Does that get processed on Snowflake itself and then result is returned or is that processed as a spark job on client EMR ? When i see the history of queries on Snowflake there also it shows the executed query. Does it mean it consumes the resources there as well ?

Answer (score 3):

The Spark Connector applies predicate and query pushdown by capturing and analyzing the Spark logical plans for SQL operations. When the data source is Snowflake, the operations are translated into a SQL query and then executed in Snowflake to improve performance.

However, because this translation requires almost a one-to-one translation of Spark SQL operators to Snowflake expressions, not all of Spark SQL operators can be pushed down. When pushdown fails, the connector falls back to a less-optimized execution plan. The unsupported operations are instead performed in Spark.

Comment: does it mean if I give any operator in query to do filter etc, all of that is performed on snowflake itself. It will simply return the filtered dataframe which i use further in my jobs. That filter operation will not actually run on spark.

Comment: Really good point about the translation between spark <-> snowflake and how that affects pushdown/the query plan. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Snowflake Connector enables Spark to read data from, and write data to, Snowflake.

The client is sending the query through the Spark Connector to Snowflake which process it and returns the result to the connector.

As the query execution is handled by Snowflake, it will consume your Snowflake credits.